# WCF Service calling a unmanaged c++ dll which has complex datatypes

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, dll, unmanaged

First of all I am sorry if I have ask the question which has an answer already. I have done some research but I couldn't get what I want. I am new to WCF service, so please bear with me, So here is the situation, I have an unmanaged c++ dll which has complex data types such as structs, unions also it has some user defined data types. What I need is to connect this unmanaged c++ from a wcf service(c#). I have two options for this
1. marshaling the complex types of unmanaged c++ dll to c# types.
2. creating another unmanaged c++ dll which accepts basic data types from my wcf service and it tries to map this basic data types to the complex datatypes in the present c++ dll.

I want to know which is a better solution also I want to know how I can accomplish the second option. please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how complex you data types are: if the data types are not very complex, use the 1st one; if very complex, like array of structures,  you might want to use 2nd one.

For the 1st approach, the implementation is simple, you just have to make sure the data type in both managed side(C#) and unmanaged side(native C++) has the same layout, this MSDN [Marshaling Data with Platform Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzhhdwae(v=vs.110).aspx) gives example on how to do it. It is easy to implement, but hard to debug. Such as, if the structs in C# and C# have a very small difference, such as a char field in C#  struct is mapped to a int field in C++, you program will just crash and no details about it. The marshaller is like a black box, you have to read a lot of documentation to understand what's going on inside. This approach is called explicit PInvoke

For the 2nd approach, first it is mix C++(C++\CLI) DLL project, not a native one. C++/CLI can access both native and managed resource, so it can be use as a bridge here. Basic, you need to implement a wrapper for the native C++ DLL in C++\CLI, there's will be a lot of implementation work, but you know what is going on and it's easier to debug. This approach is called C++ Interop (Implicit PInvoke).

As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2x8kf7zx.aspx) says: C++ Interop is recommended over explicit PInvoke because it provides better type safety, is typically less tedious to implement, is more forgiving if the unmanaged API is modified, and makes performance enhancements possible that are not possible with explicit PInvoke.